# Ionic2 / Angular2 - send data to first page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

How can I send data generated on a page up the navCtrl stack all the way down to the root page?
I tried `this.navCtrl.first().component` but it returns only the type of the object and not the real page object. 
I thought of something like this 
`this.navCtrl.first().component.setData(this.someValue)`

Is there a way to do that or should I look into a message broadcasting solution?

---

Fixed : use the `instance` attribute of `this.navCtrl.first()` -> `this.navCtrl.first().instance` is the page object

Comment: Not getting your problem, can you please repeat again ?

Answer (score 0):

To propage data from the top of the `navCtrl` stack to the root controller use the `instance` attribute of `this.navCtrl.first()` => `this.navCtrl.first().instance`.
`instance` is the root controller object and you can and access it's methods / attributes.